# What are the most promising approches for solving Riemann hypothesis?

Tags: riemann-hypothesis

I'm not a mathematician but still I'm very interested in Riemann hypothesis. I discovered it with the Numberphile channel. I would like to know what are the current work done of this subject and if there are any promising method to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You might look at Peter Borwein's recent book "[The Riemann Hypothesis: A Resource for the Afficionado and Virtuoso Alike](https://books.google.ca/books?id=faH7fhEE4UEC&dq=%22Riemann%20hypothesis%22)".

Answer (score 1):

This question has been partially addressed at mathoverflow. See the question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34699/approaches-to-riemann-hypothesis-using-methods-outside-number-theory, which focuses on methods outside number theory, and also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96642/current-status-of-the-riemann-hypothesis. It appears at present that there is no really promising approach, but I may be very wrong.

Comment: The book "[Prime Numbers and the Riemann Hypothesis][1]".
may be of interest, since it is by mathematicians but is mainly intended (it seems to me) for non-mathematicians.
While it does not address your question specifically, it has a wealth of information about r.h. and its implications.
  [1]: http://wstein.org/rh/rh.pdf

Possibly this blog about a possible connection to quasicrystals would be of interest as well:
https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2013/06/quasicrystals_and_the_riemann.html (I didn't intend this to be a comment on a comment).